# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a code to webscrape the data from the table on a nasdaq page to analyse without using pandas or Numpy but I keep trying different methods and attribute errors keep occurring

i've tried watching tutorials and using different parsers but nothings working

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
#setting webpage
my_url = requests.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market- 
activity/stocks/rshpf/historical").text

#grabbing webpage and opening the connect

#does html parser
page_soup = soup(my_url, "xml")
table = soup.find("table")
```

I expect to see the html text for the table

Comment: What's the exact error with trace?

Comment: To go off of what @Carcigenicate is (I think) getting at - is the title the error you're getting? I find that particularly hard to believe considering `find_all` is mentioned nowhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: @esqew That's why I want to know the stack trace. Either this code isn't correct, or some code of theirs is delegating to `find_all`, and bad data is being passed.

Comment: Sorry but what is stack trace or how do I find it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamic and the data is rendered after you are pulling the html, which means the table tag is null.

You can get the data from the API and then convert to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/RSHPF/historical'

payload = {
'assetclass': 'stocks',
'fromdate': '2019-10-06',
'limit': '100',
'todate': '2019-11-06'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data']['tradesTable']['rows'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
    close        date   high    low   open  volume
0   $1.97  11/05/2019  $1.97  $1.97  $1.97     N/A
1   $1.97  11/04/2019  $1.97  $1.97  $1.97     N/A
2   $1.97  11/01/2019  $1.97  $1.97  $1.97  12,600
3   $1.96  10/31/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
4   $1.96  10/30/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
5   $1.96  10/29/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
6   $1.96  10/28/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
7   $1.96  10/25/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
8   $1.96  10/24/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
9   $1.96  10/23/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
10  $1.96  10/22/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
11  $1.96  10/21/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
12  $1.96  10/18/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
13  $1.96  10/17/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
14  $1.96  10/16/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96     N/A
15  $1.96  10/15/2019  $1.96  $1.96  $1.96   7,650
16     $2  10/14/2019     $2     $2     $2     N/A
17     $2  10/11/2019     $2     $2     $2     N/A
18     $2  10/10/2019     $2     $2     $2     250
19     $2  10/09/2019     $2     $2     $2     250
20     $2  10/08/2019     $2     $2     $2     N/A
21     $2  10/07/2019     $2     $2     $2     200
```